# Cron job has started producing output

Tags: cron, drush

I have a cron job

/www/www/job.execute.sh

That runs the civiCRM scheduled tasks:

```
#!/bin/sh
drush -r /home/crwheelmen/www/www --quiet civicrm-api job.execute
```

This has been running successfully without any output for months. Now it has started producing this output:

```
Array
(
[is_error] => 0
[version] => 3
[count] => 1
[values] => 1
)
```

which has the effect of sending me an email with this content every hour. AFAIK, I did nothing to cause this, but it is very annoying. Do you know why this has started happening?

Comment: Would be useful to know what version you are running. Have you upgraded recently. I've also seen an unhelpful change in behaviour after an upgrade. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/29176/blank-emails-from-cron-after-upgrade-wordpress. But I'm running in a different environment

Comment: This happened after an upgrade to version 5.11.0

Comment: Same upgrade as caused my unwanted emails.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why it's suddenly started producing output when it didn't previously, but you could use:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=`drush -r /home/crwheelmen/www/www --quiet civicrm-api job.execute`
if echo $a | grep -qv '\[is_error\] => 0'; then echo $a; fi
```

(capture the output of drush to variable `a` then check whether `is_error` is 0.  If it is, do nothing otherwise show the output)